# Forcing page number to start from the title page

Tags: titles, page-numbering

My code is the following:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[font=bf, labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{endnotes}

    \begin{document}


    \title{some title}
    \singlespace{\author{author stuff}}

    \maketitle


    \newpage
    \begin{abstract}
      abstract stuff
    \end{abstract}

    \newpage
    \doublespace

    \section*{Introduction}

    blah blah blah

    \end{document}
```

When I compile this, page 1 starts on the third page (i.e., on the page where the section Introduction starts). However, I want page 1 to begin from the title page, then abstract page would be page 2, and introduction page would be page 3 and so on. How can I do this?

Note that I want the page numbers to actually show. That is, on the bottom of the title page, the number 1 needs to show.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have started hacking the `\thispagestyle` and `\setcounter` commands, but it wasn't a good idea, please try `\addtocounter{page}{2}`, I enclose an example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
% Beginning of hack...
%\let\oldthispagestyle=\thispagestyle % If we want to see a page number.
%\def\thispagestyle#1{} % If we want to see a page number.
%\let\oldsetcounter=\setcounter
%\def\setcounter#1#2{}
% End of hack...
\singlespacing
\title{My title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\newpage
\begin{abstract}
  Abstract stuff.
\end{abstract}
\newpage
\doublespacing
\addtocounter{page}{2}
% Restore commands...
%\let\thispagestyle=\oldthispagestyle % If we want to see a page number.
%\let\setcounter=\oldsetcounter
% End of restoring commands...
\section*{Introduction}
My first page.
\newpage
Another text.
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: @TrueTears Really? Doesn't look like there are numbers on the title and abstract pages, but the image is a little small!

Comment: @Malipovo could it be that your original hack did do this, but the `\addtocounter` method doesn't (i.e. it just increases the counter for the pages where the page number is already displayed?

Comment: @FionaSmith I believed that there shouldn't be page numbers on page 1 and 2, it could be arranged if OP wanted that.

Comment: @Malipivo, in the question by TrueTears it is said "Note that I want the page numbers to actually show. That is, on the bottom of the title page, the number 1 needs to show." I would be really grateful if you could arrange this.

Comment: Thanks. Needed to start first page from 'Page 2' and adding `\addtocounter{page}{1}` after `\begin{document}` did the trick

Answer (score 14):

The `titlepage` environment in the `article` class resets the page number to 1 both at the beginning and at the end; when the `titlepage` option is specified, `abstract` uses the `titlepage` environment internally. Since you want continuous numbering, the remedy is to redefine `titlepage` in order to remove the page number resetting.

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[font=bf, labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{titlepage}
 {%
  \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
  \else
    \@restonecolfalse\newpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
 }
 {%
  \if@restonecol
    \twocolumn
  \else
    \newpage
  \fi
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\title{some title}
\author{author stuff}

\maketitle


\newpage
\begin{abstract}
  abstract stuff
\end{abstract}

\newpage
\doublespacing

\section*{Introduction}

blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

Note that `\doublespace` is wrong (not only typographically): the correct declaration is `\doublespacing`. Also `\singlespace` doesn't take an argument (and it is wrong in the same way); until you don't issue `\doublespacing`, `\singlespacing` is implied.

It's easy to show the page numbers also in the title page and in the abstract page:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[font=bf, labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{titlepage}
 {%
  \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
  \else
    \@restonecolfalse\newpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
 }
 {%
  \if@restonecol
    \twocolumn
  \else
    \newpage
  \fi
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\title{some title}
\author{author stuff}

\maketitle


\newpage
\begin{abstract}
  abstract stuff
\end{abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\newpage
\doublespacing

\section*{Introduction}

blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a general answer. IMHO it is better solution than Malipivo answer.

Comment: @jpayansomet I agree with you, but try to explain this solution to a TeX beginner.

Comment: How would you adapt this for the book document class?

Comment: @AurélienOoms This should be a new question, because it may depend on the options you pass to the class.

Comment: @egreg, your example Displays on the third page the number 3, but unfortunately on the title and abstract page there are no numbers displayed (what is requested by @TrueTears).

Comment: @Qaswed Thanks for noting; I added the needed changes.

Answer (score 1):

I took your file, removed the titlepage option in `\documentclass`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{harvard}
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[font=bf, labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\begin{document}


\title{some title}
\singlespace{\author{author stuff}}

\maketitle




\newpage
\begin{abstract}
  abstract stuff
\end{abstract}

\newpage
\doublespace

\section*{Introduction}

blah blah blah

\end{document}
```