# Title page should be counted/increment but must not display page numbering on title?

Tags: titles, page-numbering

I'm facing an interesting question about the numbering and counting of the pages. Here is how my article should look like in terms of page numberging :

Title page : count for page 1, but not numbered
Abstract and so on : count for page 2+, numbered in roman II, III, etc,
Main part : count start again on page 1, numbered in arabic 1, 2, 3, etc

So my MWE is working fine, it uses the `titlepage` environment to create a custom title. The `pagenumbering` commands are fine for switching the type of numerbing.

This difficult part was to actually make the titlepage count as a "page 1". I manage to do this by artificially incrementing the counter on page.

**My questions :**

- Does the `pagenumbering` always reset the page count ?
- Is the incrementation of the counter (relatively) safe to do ?
- Isn't there a cleaner was to achieve the same results ?

Here is my MWE code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\CustomTitle}{%
    \begin{titlepage} % Start of page
    \Huge{A Title}
    \end{titlepage}
}

\begin{document}
% title
\CustomTitle%
% \addtocounter{page}{1} % <- artificially increment counter
\clearpage%
% Front matter
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\section*{a dummy abstract}
\lipsum[11]
\clearpage
\section*{a dummy executive summary}
\lipsum[4]
\clearpage
\section*{another dummy frontmatter}
\clearpage%
% Main
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[4-12]\clearpage

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[13-23]\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Update 22/08/2019

Actually, [there was a similar issue on Tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171976/forcing-page-number-to-start-from-the-title-page). I'll go through the answers already provided

Comment: `\thispagestyle{empty}` should do the trick.

Comment: Don't use the `titlepage` environment. All it does is messing with page numbers and setting the pagestyle to `empty`. You *just* want the latter, so use the line Bernard gave you in the comment above.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, indeed for a simple title, the \maketitle would be enough, but I forgot to mention that my title page is slightly more complex with image and bloc of texte, etc.

Comment: You can have anything you want on your title page, just don't use the titlepage environment.

Comment: @Johannes_B : I've tried to renew the command \maketitle and to include all the content I previously had in the titlepage, it worked fine. Do you want to provide some answer accordingly and maybe offer some context on why it is so bad to use it ?

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192870/how-to-use-pagenumbering-in-the-document/208208#208208

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,`\pagenumbering` resets the page counter.

Here is a modified version of `\CustomTitle` which does what you want, if I've well understood:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\CustomTitle}{%
    \begin{titlepage}%\thispagestyle{empty} % Start of page
    \Huge{A Title}
    \end{titlepage}
\stepcounter{page}
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
% title
\CustomTitle%

\section*{a dummy abstract}
\lipsum[11]
\clearpage
\section*{a dummy executive summary}
\lipsum[4]
\clearpage
\section*{another dummy frontmatter}
\clearpage%
% Main
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[4-12]\clearpage

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[13-23]\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]